# Change subsite to a site

Tags: site

We have recently undergone organizational changes and I'd like to organize the site to reflect this.  I need to move a subsite that was originally under a main site, up a level in navigation so that it is now a site.
Example...EEO Dept used be a subsite of HR.  I can easily move/change this subsite so that it depends on another department, using "site content and structure" in the Site Collecation Administration area. In this case though, I'd like EEO Dept to be at the same level as HR or the other main sites.  When I try to move it up one level in the hierarchy, I get the error "Cannot manually move or copy an item to the Drop Off library"

Is there another way to accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: I found this answer, but I'm afraid to deactivate since I'm unsure of what settings might depend on this one...
Hi,

 

Please go to the destination site > site settings > site actions > manage site features to deactivate the “content organizer” feature and then move again.

Comment: You'll want to get a copy of the content organizer rules if you deactivate the feature as I believe you'll need to rebuild the rules.  You might want to do a backup and restore to the new location instead.